# How to hide new-line characters in Scintilla?

Tags: c++, scintilla

I'm creating a dark theme for a Scintilla based editor. I've managed to define all styles as I wanted, except for the line endings. In other words, despite all the text in my editor being showed on a dark background, at the end of each line there's a small white-filled rectangle.

I believe this rectangle is related to line-feed character, because even empty lines have it. But no other control characters are being displayed.

So, how can I get rid of this white rectangle?

I've tried to change the ControlCharSymbol to other values (under or above 0x20) and got no result.

Note: I've just noticed that the same occurs for white-spaces and tabs if they are set to be INVISIBLE. If they are set to be visible, Scintilla shows them as '.' and '--->' using the colors I've defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already set the background for all the styles defined by the lexer, you might also try [setting the background](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_STYLESETBACK) for [STYLE_DEFAULT](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#StyleDefinition).

If that doesn't work, the background can be set globally for all whitespace using [SCI_SETWHITESPACEBACK](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETWHITESPACEBACK).

Comment: SCI_SETWHITESPACEBACK (along with SCI_SETWHITESPACEFORE with the same values for default background) works for hiding the white-spaces. But the small rectangle at the end of each line is still visible.

Comment: @Alex. Hmm, curious. I can't reproduce that at all. What lexer are you using? Do you get the same result if you use a different eol mode?

Comment: you're right. Using STYLE_DEFAULT followed by SCI_STYLECLEARALL set all styles to default. Then I just need to change only the styles I really want. Thanks!